# Unable to link from source code to header file present in selective path defined in Android.mk

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, android-ndk

I'm working on an Android App, that needs to pick a header file from directory based on what variant the build is being compiled for.

Both `Android.mk` and `source.c` are present in the root folder. At the same level exist 2 folders, each with the same named header file **BUT** different contents:

./folder1/headerx.h

./folder2/headerx.h

`Android.mk` defines which folder to go look for in the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` variable and this definition works fine. Here `$(SUB_FOLDER)` is a system variable that equates to either `folder1` or `folder1`:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)  
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SUB_FOLDER)
```

source.c includes the header file with:

```
#include "headerx.h"
```

I expect `source.c` to correctly include `headerx.h` because the relevant folder location has been selected and included in `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` but of course am faced with

```
fatal error: 'headerx.h' file not found
```

What am I doing wrong? Using `#include "folder1/headerx.h"` works but the whole point is to avoid doing that because `source.c` is not aware of which folder to use. `Android.mk` is aware so I have to make the selection there.

I'm fairly new to Android NDK so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried logging the actual include paths when you build (e.g. by adding `-v` to your `LOCAL_CFLAGS`, or by using `$(info $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES))` ?

Comment: Yes, I have.  And that part seems to be working correctly. Logging as above gives me:   `root/folder1` when system variable selects `folder1`